# Databricks CLI Error databricks-connect' is not recognized

Tags: pip, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

Databricks CLI worked a year and half ago, when I last worked with it. Since then I have mostly used API. Now, I wanted to use Databricks CLI again (on a new PC) and it does not work.

```
"The term 'databricks-connect' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"
```

I have done the following:

1. Followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/ and did `pip3 install databricks-cli`
2. When I do pip3 install databricks-cli now, I see it says "Requirement already satisfied: databricks-cli in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (0.14.3)"
3. I have set c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages in the path variable
   Someone mentioned it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/145963/databricks-cli-not-working-properly.html
4. When trying to execute databricks-connect -configure, I still get an error saying: "The term 'databricks-connect' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"
5. I have looked within the site-packages (the same path that I have in path that I mentioned above) and see this structure:

[image]

What am I missing?

Even databricks --version does not work.

What is it that I am missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing things - `databricks-connect`  command is from `databricks-connect` package, the `databricks-cli` package provides only `databricks` and `dbfs` commands.

On Windows the scripts installed by `databricks-cli` are installed into the [`Scripts` folder](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable) under the root of Python installation (I think that it should be `c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python37\Scripts` in your case).  So you need to add it into the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks but if you look at my post- I had posted a link to Microsoft's documentation , where it talks about that to use Databricks CLI, we have to first set it up and in the setup section , using PAT, the databricks-connect --configure was mentioned . I understand that it is a separate package, but I also have that installed. Also, in the same post (at the end) I had mentioned that even databricks --version does not work (which according to the MS docs is way to check the version of the CLI). It still does not work. I even added the scripts folder to the path but still the same error.

Comment: the documentation that you linked doesn't mention `databricks-connect` at all - it says run `databricks configure --token` to configure it.  but you can just create the file manually.

Comment: You are right, I mixed it up because I was setting up Databricks connect and the CLI for 2 different tasks. It works now. Thanks ! I had to add the Scripts folder to the path , like you mentioned.  Now even the databricks --version works. thanks !